how to detect another player from
local UserInputService = game:GetService("UserInputService")
local RunService = game:GetService("RunService")
local plr = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer
local char = plr.Character or plr.CharacterAdded:Wait()
local hum = char:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
local root = hum.RootPart

local pcKey = Enum.KeyCode.LeftShift
local xboxKey = Enum.KeyCode.DPadLeft
local isActive = false

function shiftLock()
    isActive = not isActive
    if isActive then
        hum.CameraOffset = Vector3.new(1.75, 0, 0)
        hum.AutoRotate = false
        RunService:BindToRenderStep("ShiftLock", Enum.RenderPriority.Character.Value, function()
            UserInputService.MouseBehavior = Enum.MouseBehavior.LockCenter
            local rootCFrame = root.CFrame
            local cameraLookVector = workspace.CurrentCamera.CFrame.LookVector
            local newCFrame = CFrame.new(rootCFrame.Position, rootCFrame.Position + Vector3.new(cameraLookVector.X, 0, cameraLookVector.Z))
            root.CFrame = newCFrame
        end)
    else
        hum.CameraOffset = Vector3.new(0, 0, 0)
        hum.AutoRotate = true
        RunService:UnbindFromRenderStep("ShiftLock")
        UserInputService.MouseBehavior = Enum.MouseBehavior.Default
    end
end
shiftLock()

UserInputService.InputBegan:Connect(function(input, process)
    if process then return end
    if input.KeyCode == pcKey or input.KeyCode == xboxKey then
        shiftLock()
    end
end)

Im trying to make a Custom Roblox Shift lock Script for Xbox and PC And gonna add mobile support soon but my rotation is really janky. Like the camera shakes when at high speeds. Is there any better way to do this without altering the original Roblox ShiftLock Script? Like new calculations or better smootheners without any delay.

Well to help this is a simple mistake, you first need to not do such a chunky code block and make it smaller to have the code not get tied up with risking a jitter the player can notice, and may end up having the parts of your player's body get out of place for a frame and then bug out to get even worse!
Avoid big code and use the more built-in ROBLOX locking mouse, that's already shift lock code, made for you!
And ROBLOX actually really already has plugins for all of this so using that you can easily take that and edit it, if you want to, aides, ROBLOX is full of over 2M games using those plugins and I bet you'll find something that works for you!

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

well I'm trying to make my own script because I do not have access to Plugins or Built In Roblox Code due to me using roblox studio Mobile (Studio Lite) so I cant really get a good script
